# Use of pageToken with Google Analytics Reporting API v4 and Python

Tags: python, api, google-analytics

I have followed a tutorial on how to download data from Google Analytics with Python using GA Reporting API. I was able to query the data I wanted, although reaching the rows limit. 
I saw in the documentation that there is a pageToken to avoid the issue. I have added this field to my request (as describe in the documentation), but I am not able to make it work.

```
sample_request = {
      'viewId': '12345678',
      'dateRanges': {
          'startDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 30),'%Y-%m-%d'),
          'endDate': datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),'%Y-%m-%d')
      },
      'dimensions': [
          {'name': 'ga:date'},
          {'name': 'ga:dimension7'},
          {'name': 'ga:dimension6'},
          {'name': 'ga:dimension9'}
      ],
      'metrics': [
          {'expression': 'ga:users'},
          {'expression': 'ga:totalevents'}
      ],
      "pageSize": 100000,
      'pageToken': 'abc'
    }

response = api_client.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': sample_request
      }).execute()
```

Comment: The API has probably set a maximum number of rows to be extracted. Check if there are any limits in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Indeed, there is a limit. You can nonetheless use the pageToken parameter to overcome this issue. How you do it is actually my question.

Answer (score 5):

You will hit the limit, but the parameter *nextPageToken* will allow you to page through multiple rows.  For example:

```
def processReport (self, aDimensions):
    """Get a full report, returning the rows"""

    # Get the first set
    oReport   = self.getReport(aDimensions)
    oResponse = self.getResponse(oReport, True)
    aRows     = oResponse.get('rows')

    # Add any additional sets
    while oResponse.get('nextPageToken') != None:
        oResponse = self.getReport(aDimensions, oResponse.get('nextPageToken'))
        oResponse = self.getResponse(oResponse, False)
        aRows.extend(oResponse.get('rows'))

    return aRows
```

You can see the complete program here:
https://github.com/aiqui/ga-download

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wrote a recursive function to check whether the request is giving back nextPageToken, and then assigned that value to the pageToken parameter and do another request.

https://pastebin.com/nt2uRWVj

Apparently I am not receaving any nextPageToken back.

Comment: I checked out your code.  It looks like you're on the right track.  I would reduce the pageSize parameter to be much lower, say 10, and see if you are getting back the nextPageToken parameter.  That's also a good way to minimize the traffic while testing.

Comment: I am still not getting the nextPageToken parameter with `pagesize:10`, and for the reasons why this is happening I am now totally blind. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I figured it out. I was checking the parameter with `response.get('nextPageToken')`. As it is dictionary, I am using `response['reports'][0]['nextPageToken']`. Now it sees it and I can use my recursive function. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Hi @E.Faslo and @Charlie Hileman, I am trying to query the same reports but with no success, could you check my code and let me know if you find any mistakes? Even when passing the `pageToken` I am still getting the same rows as before.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this

```
def handle_report(analytics,pagetoken,rows):  

    response = get_report(analytics, pagetoken)

    columnHeader = response.get("reports")[0].get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    pagetoken = response.get("reports")[0].get('nextPageToken', None)
    rowsNew = response.get("reports")[0].get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
    rows = rows + rowsNew
    print("len(rows): " + str(len(rows)))

    if pagetoken != None:
        return handle_report(analytics,pagetoken,rows)
    else:
        return rows

def main():    
    analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()

    global dfanalytics
    dfanalytics = []

    rows = []
    rows = handle_report(analytics,'0',rows)

    dfanalytics = pd.DataFrame(list(rows))
```